# how to generate kubernetes deployment yaml file using template generator

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am kubernetes newbie, and I have a basic question

my understanding from https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/conventions/ is , we can generate yaml templates using "kubernetes run" command

But when I tried doing same, it didn't work as expected

```
kubectl run deployment-sample --image deployment-sample --dry-run -o yaml --generator=extensions/v1beta1
error: generator "extensions/v1beta1" not found


kubectl run deployment-sample --image deployment-sample --dry-run -o yaml --generator=apps/v1beta1
error: generator "apps/v1beta1" not found
```

Not sure if my understanding is wrong or something wrong in my command ?

I am on kubernetes 1.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that I can create a Deployment with `kubectl run --generator=deployment/v1beta1 foobar --image=nginx -o yaml --dry-run` so your case would be `kubectl run --generator=deployment/v1beta1 deployment-sample --image=deployment-sample -o yaml --dry-run`. The kubectl conventions page you refer to does say this generator is 'recommended' for Deployments.

But I'm not sure why the docs list a non-recommended generator option that actually doesn't work. For a command like this you can recreate the expected output in a reference environment through the online tutorials at https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/create-cluster/cluster-interactive/ You get the same output there so it is not just you or your cluster. My best guess is that 'extensions/v1beta1' [is too general to match to a deployment specifically](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/federation/extensions/v1beta1/definitions/). It [could well be that the documentation needs changing on this](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues/12090).